# How can I return the needed type for a closure from a void function or closure?

Tags: swift

I have a function called `callTest` like this:

```
func test(bool: @escaping () -> Bool) {
    print(bool())
}

func toDo(value: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    value(Bool.random())
}

func callTest() {
    
    test(bool: {

        toDo(value: { inComingValue in
            return inComingValue
        })

    })
    
}
```

I want to find the ways around of converting value of type '()' to closure result type. How we can correctly or possibly return needed type for a closure form a child void function which has same type closure as parent?

Comment: This question makes no sense to another person. Can you make it make sense to us? It will need closing otherwise.

Comment: This is a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75894367/how-make-for-loop-wait-for-our-signal-for-next-item) by the looks of it

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Oh I didn't realise the similarity in the user names! I had suspected it, but after looking at this OP's profile, I saw that this OP has not posted any other questions, so I thought it was just my imagination.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not absolutely sure what you are asking for, but your code won't compile for a number of reasons.

`todo` expects a closure of type `(Bool) -> Void`. That means you can't return a non void value. However, in `callTest`, you pass it

```
{ inComingValue in return inComingValue }
```

This is a function that has type `(SomeType) -> SomeType`. `SomeType` is inferred to be `Bool` in this context, so the function is the wrong type to pass to `todo`.

You also have the reverse problem in that `test` expects a closure of type `() -> Bool` but you pass it a closure that returns `Void`.

Basically, everything has to return `Bool` in this example.

```
func test(bool: () -> Bool) {
    print(bool())
}

func toDo(value: (Bool) -> Bool) -> Bool 
//                                  ^^^^ Returns Bool
{
    return value(Bool.random())
}

func callTest() {

    test(bool: {

        return toDo(value: { inComingValue in
            return inComingValue
        })
    })

}
```

I removed the `@escaping` annotations because they are unnecessary in this case. The closures do not outlive the scope of the function.

I also put explicit `return`s in everywhere to make it obvious you are returning something. These aren't necessary in recent versions of Swift because they are implied if you have a block with only one statement in it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it looks like good but it has a small issue that makes it not usable for my issue, the `toDo` function in my question has not to return a value and it is void function, in yours it must return a bool value, with your function I cannot use timer or DispatchQueue that makes a return for toDo, with my function in question I am be able to return the closure when the timer or DispatchQueue finished the work. Also toDo function is not about timer or DispatchQueue, it simply means it working and it would take some time to be able return some thing as closure.

Comment: @morehotcode25 If you can't change `todo` you can't use it as the parameter to `test`. What are you allowed to change?